# Changing The Last Element in a String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to solve this problem:

"Petar likes to play with numbers. He is very good with strings too. One day he decided to invent a new game of summing numbers. He will get one number and will try to divide it by 5, if the number can be divided without remainder (for example 15 can be divided by 5 without remainder, but 17 divided by 5 is 3 with remainder 2) Petar will add this number to the sum. However if the number cannot be divided without remainder, only the remainder will be added to the sum. After he is done with the numbers, Petar likes to replace some of the sum's digits with strings. If the sum is odd he will replace the last digit and all others that are the same as it with a given string. If the sum is even he will do the same, but with the first digit. For example, if the sum is 2434, and the string is "a" - the result will be a434.
You will be given a start number, an end number and a string. You have to check all numbers between the start number and the end number (without the end number), do Petar's algorithm and finally replace the digits with the string as described above.

**Input**

The input data should be read from the console. It consists of three lines:
•   The first line will hold the starting number;
•   The second  line will hold the end number;
•   The third like will hold the replacement string
The input data will always be valid and in the format described. There is no need to check it explicitly."

My current code looks like so, it compiles but when I input the values I get an error at line 49, I cannot use debug for some reason I get an error from VisualStudio, so can you please have a look at it for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;


namespace Petar_s_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ulong startNum = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ulong endNum = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string replacementStr = Console.ReadLine();
            List<ulong> list = new List<ulong>();
            ulong sum = 0;
            List<string> sumStrArr = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; startNum < endNum; startNum++)
            {
                if (startNum % 5 == 0)
                {
                    list.Add(startNum);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(startNum % 5);
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                sum =+ item;
            }

            string sumStr = sum.ToString();
            foreach (var item in sumStr)
            {
                sumStrArr.Add(Char.ToString(item));
            }
            if (IsEven(sum))
            {
                sumStrArr[0] = replacementStr;
            }
            if (IsEven(sum) == false)
            {
                sumStrArr[(sumStrArr.Capacity) - 1] = replacementStr;
            }
        }
        public static bool IsEven(ulong n)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, at least you could point at what is the line 49 in your sources. And what is the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `List<T>.Capacity`. Capacity is the [*total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should be using [`List<T>.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the amount of elements.

Replace this:

```
if (IsEven(sum) == false)
{
    sumStrArr[(sumStrArr.Capacity) - 1] = replacementStr;
}
```

With

```
if (IsEven(sum) == false)
{
    sumStrArr[sumStrArr.Count - 1] = replacementStr;
}
```

By the way, you seem to be calling `IsEven` twice here - instead of doing

```
if (IsEven(sum))
{
    // ...
}
if (IsEven(sum) == false)
{
    // ...
}
```

Do this:

```
if (IsEven(sum))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```